# With pandas, how to resample and apply a function to add a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm totally new to pandas and doing my first steps. I'm stuck even researching brings nothing up, most likely I'm not using the right terms.

I have initial data in the following form

```
           datetime    counter
2019-06-01 17:57:54  159411631
2019-06-01 17:57:54  159411642
2019-06-01 17:57:54  159411642
2019-06-01 17:58:03  159411642
2019-06-01 17:58:03  159411643
```

This represents the cumulative total value of my electric consumption directly read from the counter.

I would now like to calculate the consumption per day from this data.

I'm trying to resampling the data per date:

```
res = df.resample('D').max() - df.resample('D').min()
```

This does not work as pandas does not know how to subtract the date column. I don't know how to select just one column... and I'm not sure selecting a column explicitly is the pandas'ish way to do.

What would be the right way to get the daily consumption from the above data?

```
      date  consumption
2019-06-01         3968 
2019-06-02         9491
2019-06-03        20444
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and add parameter `on` to `resample`:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
res = (df.resample('D', on='datetime')['counter'].max() - 
       df.resample('D', on='datetime')['counter'].min())
```

Or create `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df = df.set_index('datetime')
res = (df.resample('D').max() - 
       df.resample('D').min()).reset_index().rename(columns={'counter':'consumption'})
```

---

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df = df.set_index('datetime')
res = df.resample('D').agg(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())
```

And last convert `Series` to `DataFrame`:

```
res = res.reset_index(name='consumption')
print (res)
    datetime  consumption
0 2019-06-01           12
```